# React.createElement issue: TS2322 Type T is not assignable to type ReactElement<{}>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have code that currently creates a React element for testing like this

```
let titleElement : ReactElement<{}> = React.createElement(Title);
const component = shallow(titleElement);
const text = component.text();
expect(text).toBe("test");
```

with the Title element looking like this

```
import * as React from "react";
import {Component, ReactElement} from "react";

export class Title extends Component<{}, {}> {     
  public render() : ReactElement<any> {
    return <p>test</p>;
  }     
}
```

I get warnings that React.createClass is deprecated, so I want to move over to plan JavaScript classes instead. Hence I've tried

```
let titleElement: ReactElement<{}> = new Title();
const component = shallow(titleElement);
const text = component.text();
expect(text).toBe("test");
```

but running tsc then yields

```
TS2322: Type 'Title' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<{}>'.
Property 'type' is missing in type 'Title'.
```

Why?

Comment: React.createElement shouldn't give a warning about React.createClass. Are you sure it's not something else?

Comment: @jontro Hmm good point, possibly createElement is not involved. But tsc nonetheless gives the TS2322 error on my attempt to create a Title element.

Comment: My understanding is that you're not supposed to initialise a react component directly, instead you need to use createElement as in your initial attempt

Comment: @jontro then maybe I'm misunderstanding this https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-react.createclass?

Comment: `createClass` is not the same thing as `createElement` https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement

Comment: Ah of course! Thanks @jontro! Now I'll just have to figure out where the warning I see is coming from :)

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't an issue at all as the warning was unrelated. So the solution is to not try and do what I did :)

Thanks @jontro!